# php subtract discounts from while loop

Tags: php, loops, points, discount

I need to subtract points from the cart as a discount, my cart hold for example items for 3 restaurants.

-- $points = 40;

- Restaurant 1

  - item1 $5
  - item2 $2

--Total: $7

- Restaurant 2

  - item1 $8
  - item2 $4

--Total: $12

- Restaurant 3

  - item1 $9

--Total: $9

Now, randomly I want to subtract from each restaurant amount from the points and delete these points from the user account.

In my example the total is $28 and my points is 40 so 40-28= 12 Points left
and the cart total will be 0

Here is my try:

```
$points = 40;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   $price = $row['price'];
   ...
   ...
   $total = $row['total']; // To here everything is OK.

   $discount = $total - $points; // To subtract 40 for each restaurant and this is not what I want !!
}
```

Comment: You should substract total from points, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but my test will subtract 40 from the total for each restaurant, I want to divide the points for the 3 restaurants  and subtract randomly

Comment: @zippax You are getting the data in variable `$r` and using `$row` to avvess the data. Also, what data are you getting from the query?